# How to resolve 'ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found ' in raspberry pi Bullseye

Tags: c++, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite

Hi I'm trying to test tenserflow video classification tutorial. Here is the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/video_classification/raspberry_pi). After all the dependancies installation, I got issue [image] Can you suggest me please a solution.

I have tried some things regarding this matter, But It doesnt work for me. [Link](https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/issues/13)

Comment: your version of tensor flow is built for a newer version of linux than the one you are using. Please don't post screenshots of text, just post the text as a properly formatted code block

Comment: So, may I need to downgrade to buster version

Comment: I have resolved by install  tflite-runtime==2.7.0 .

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR

Downgrade the pip package that requires this very GLIBCXX_3.4.29

### Longer answer

Hi, I bumped into the same issue, although it was with image classification from  the `examples` git repo (and not video classification in your case). In my stack trace, it stated that `tflite_support` was the one that required `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` which was newer than what is present in Raspberry Pi Bullseye.

I could solve the problem by downgrading this very `tflite_support` from version 0.4.4 to 0.4.3 using this command:

```bash
python -m pip install --upgrade tflite-support==0.4.3
```

I hope it can help someone more. Read the stack trace and downgrade the pip package that requires GLIBCXX_3.4.29.

To list the packages and their versions (installed locally in a virtual env), run this command:

```bash
pip list -l
```

My stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mirontoli/examples/lite/examples/image_classification/raspberry_pi/classify.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tflite_support.task import core
  File "/home/mirontoli/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tflite_support/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.python import metadata
  File "/home/mirontoli/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/python/metadata.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow_lite_support.metadata.cc.python import _pywrap_metadata_version
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/mirontoli/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow_lite_support/metadata/cc/python/_pywrap_metadata_version.so)
```

My working pip package list (as of 2023-07-13, raspberry pi 3 model b, bullseye 32bit):

```
Package        Version
-------------- --------------
absl-py        1.4.0
cffi           1.15.1
flatbuffers    20181003210633
numpy          1.25.1
opencv-python  4.5.3.56
picamera       1.13
pip            23.1.2
protobuf       3.20.3
pybind11       2.10.4
pycparser      2.21
setuptools     67.8.0
sounddevice    0.4.6
tflite-runtime 2.13.0
tflite-support 0.4.3
wheel          0.40.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Great, that worked for me ! Though I had to do an additional step of downgrading tflte-runtime as well . So what I did was:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade tflite-support==0.4.2
python -m pip install --upgrade tflite-runtime==2.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the two upgrades above, in my case (RPi4b with Buster-64bit) it was necessary to set Python3 as default. Without doing so, Python2 is default and there're are no relations to "tflite-support==0.4.2" and "tflite-runtime==2.11.0".